# Why is EditContext.OnFieldChanged not firing?

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

I have set up my code as follows:

```
protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
    Value ??= new AddressFormPageModel();
    Context = new EditContext(Value);
    Context.OnFieldChanged += OnFieldChanged;
}

private async void OnFieldChanged(object? sender, FieldChangedEventArgs e)
{
    IsValidated = false;
    if (ValueChanged.HasDelegate)
        await ValueChanged.InvokeAsync(Value);
}
```

And in my razor file I have:

```
<DxFormLayout >
    <DxFormLayoutItem Caption="Street Address:" Field="@nameof(Value.StreetNumberAndName)" ColSpanMd="12">
        <DxTextBox @bind-Text="@Value!.StreetNumberAndName" 
                   ReadOnly = "@ReadOnly"
                   ShowValidationIcon="true" />
    </DxFormLayoutItem>
...
```

When I edit  the "Street Address:" and exit it, the `OnFieldChanged` is not called. When I call `Submit` the Value object is correctly populated with the `StreetNumberAndName` value.

I did set a breakpoint on the Value.StreetNumberAndName setter and it is set when I tab from that edit box to the next.

Any idea why `OnFieldChanged` is not being called?

**Update:**

This is an inner component. It is `<AddressForm>` in the following:

```
<EditForm EditContext="EditContext"
          OnValidSubmit="HandleValidSubmitAsync"
          OnInvalidSubmit="HandleInvalidSubmitAsync"
          Context="EditFormContext">
    <ObjectGraphDataAnnotationsValidator />
    <CustomValidation @ref="_customValidation" />
    <DxFormLayout>
        <DxFormLayoutItem Caption="Unique Id:" Field="@nameof(Model.UniqueId)" ColSpanMd="4">
            <DxTextBox @bind-Text="@Model.UniqueId"
                       ReadOnly="@(ModeState != Mode.Create)"
                       ShowValidationIcon="true" />
        </DxFormLayoutItem>

        <AddressForm @ref="_addressElement"
                     ReadOnly="@(ModeState == Mode.Read)"
                     OnValidated="OnAddressValidated"
                     ValueChanged="@OnAddressChanged"
                     Value="@Model.AddressModel">
        </AddressForm>
...
```

Comment: Where is your <EditForm>?

Comment: @Lex It is in an outer component. I'll update. Is that the problem?

Comment: I don't see how `EditContext="EditContext"` and `Context = new EditContext(Value);` are linked up in any way. And when EditContxt is not linked to a Form its events will never fire.

Comment: @HH I think you're right - I was assume an EditContext declared in the inner component would just work. (I'm still learning all the details of Blazor.) I think what I need to do is pass it down [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76459366/how-should-i-handle-editcontext-model-in-an-inner-component).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

World's shortest answer - the parent EditContext needs to be passed down to the child component. It cannot make its own.

[How to do this answered here.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76460460/509627)